# how to generate thumbnail of recently taken video from camera in android using camera2 API?

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-gallery, android-camera2

`MainActivity.java` (this is the main class for all functionalities), need to generate thumbnail of videos on a corner of the camera app & when the thumbnail will be clicked it will play the video.

I have tried Recycler view but it didnt worked. Can anyone help me out ?

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;
    public static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TextureView is Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setupCamera(width, height);
            connectCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            if(mIsRecording){
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startRecord();
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                mChronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mChronometer.start();
            }else{
                startPreview();

            }
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Camera connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
           Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mVideoFileName ,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(thumb);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int i) {

        }
    };
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private String mCameraId;

    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private Size mVideoSize;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private Chronometer mChronometer;
    private int mTotalRotation;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;

    private ImageButton mRecordImageButton;
    private boolean mIsRecording = false;

    private File mVideoFolder;

    private String mVideoFileName;
    //private static File mRawVideoFileName;



    private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);

    }

    private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() / (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }
//    public static boolean contains(int[] modes, int mode){
//        if (modes == null){
//            return false;
//        }
//        for(int i : modes){
//            if(i == mode){
//                return true;
//            }
//        }
//        return  false;
//    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createVideoFolder();

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        final Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mVideoFileName, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        mRecordImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.videoButton);
        mRecordImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mIsRecording) {
                    mChronometer.stop();
                    mChronometer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mIsRecording = false;
                    mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.start_recording);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();


                    mMediaRecorder.reset();
                    Intent mediaStoreUpdateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    mediaStoreUpdateIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(mVideoFileName)));
                    sendBroadcast(mediaStoreUpdateIntent);
                    startPreview();

                } else {

                    checkWriteStoragePermission();

                    //checkWriteStoragePermission();

                }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            setupCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            connectCamera();
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permission, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permission, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application will not run without camera service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application will not have audio on record ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode== REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT){
            if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mIsRecording=true;
                mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Successfully Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"App needs to save video to run",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        if (hasFocus) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    }

    private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                if (cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
                    continue;
                }
                StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                mTotalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
                boolean swapRotation = mTotalRotation == 90 || mTotalRotation == 270;
                int rotateWidth = width;
                int rotateHeight = height;
                if (swapRotation) {
                    rotateWidth = height;
                    rotateHeight = width;
                }
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotateWidth, rotateHeight);
                mVideoSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class), rotateWidth, rotateHeight);
                mCameraId = cameraId;

                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void connectCamera() {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                } else {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Video app required access to camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
                }
            } else {
                cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void startRecord(){

        try {
            setupMediaRecorder();
            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(),mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
            Surface recordSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface,recordSurface),new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),null,null);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                }
            },null);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void startPreview() {
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        try {
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);

                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to setup Camera Preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if (mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;

        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("AuthorTV");
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundHandlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundHandlerThread.join();
            mBackgroundHandlerThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics, int deviceOrientation) {
        int sensorOrientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
        return (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
    }

    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height / width && option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
        } else {
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    private void createVideoFolder() {
        File movieFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        mVideoFolder = new File(movieFile, "AuthorTVCam");
        if (!mVideoFolder.exists()){
            mVideoFolder.mkdirs();
        }


    }


    private File createVideoFileName() throws IOException {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String prepend = "VIDEO_" + timestamp + "_";
        File videoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".mp4", mVideoFolder);
        mVideoFileName = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return videoFile;
    }

//    private File createRawVideoFileName() throws IOException {
//        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
//        String prepend = "RAW_" + timestamp + "_";
//        File rawvideoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".jpeg", mRawVideoFolder);
//        mVideoFileName = rawvideoFile.getAbsolutePath();
//        return rawvideoFile;
//    }


    private void checkWriteStoragePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mIsRecording = true;
                mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.stop_recording);
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startRecord();
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                mChronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mChronometer.start();
            } else {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "App needs to be able to save videos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT);
            }

        } else {
            mIsRecording = true;
            mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.stop_recording);
            try {
                createVideoFileName();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startRecord();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            mChronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mChronometer.start();

        }
    }
    private void setupMediaRecorder()throws IOException{
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(),mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }



}
```

activity.xml

I am not able to view the thumbnail on my camera display screen.I have attached the xml file also can you @aahmed check where is the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="70dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chronometer"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chronometer" />
        <TextureView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textureView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/videoButton"
            android:src="@mipmap/start_recording"
            android:contentDescription="@string/video_button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />


        <Chronometer
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/chronometer"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


          </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am also taking reference of this tutorial https://www.nigeapptuts.com/android-camera2-api-raw-capture/

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this below code,

```
  Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

**UPDATE**

```
 private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            if(mIsRecording){
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startRecord();
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                mChronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mChronometer.start();
            }else{
                startPreview();

            }
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Camera connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
   //here your camera disconnected, so, you can do your other UI stuffs here.
       Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mVideoFileName ,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND)
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int i) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: will it generate a thumbnail on camera display??

Comment: just give the path of the file. it will generate the bitmap then you can use it.

Comment: As I am a beginer. could you tell me where to use this code in my code (given above).and how to bring the thumbnail on the camera display that it show the latest captured video's thumbnail from the directory.

Comment: its giving a error that thumb is never used.where to use that thumb variable?And I need to display thumbnail on the same activity where the camera preview is availble.how can i do that??

Comment: save that video file path and pass it to your activity, then , you should have the ImageView. then in that imageview you can create the bitmap using above method. then you will get the bitmap as thumb. set this bitmap to imageview. like, imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb). thats all.

Comment: it is generating thumbnail but it is not passing the value of bitmap to imageview and the imageview shows null and throwing nullpointerexception.please some one help me??

Comment: What problem you faced actually. ?

Comment: Thumbnail class is for creating thumbnail which will create bitmap image in thumbnail size.  If you want to create another original bitmap , use Bitmapfactory class to create bitmap image.

Comment: if i want the imageview over the textureview(i.e.camera preview) to show the generated thumbnail in image view.so can you tell me as per this requirement is my above layout is correct??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to generate a thumbnail of a frame from your video, it is the best and Efficiency way to achieve it:

```
Glide.with(activity)
                     .load(yourVideoUri)
                     .asBitmap()
                     .override(THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_RESOLUTION, THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_RESOLUTION)
                     .into(yourImageView);
```

In other way, if you want to set your video in a view, you should use a `VideoView`. Here is an example about how to do it:

```
 @Override public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mp.setLooping(true);
      videoContainer.start();
      videoContainer.seekTo(VIDEO_START_VALUE);     
   }

   @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
      //Manage onCompletion callback if necessary
   }
```